# Almost sure convergence of sequence of R.V. using bounds on expected value

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

I am trying to solve the following:

Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,...$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space
$(\Omega, F, P)$ such that $E|\xi_n| \le 2^{-n}$. I want to show that $ \xi_n \to 0$ a.s. as $n \to \infty$.

I know this amounts to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ that $P(lim_{n \to \infty}|\xi_n| < \epsilon)=1$.  I am just confused on how to start using the bounds on the expected value of $\xi_n$ to show the almost sure convergence.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

1. Show that the random variable $\sum_{n=1}^{ +\infty}\left|\xi_n\right|$ is integrable, hence almost surely finite.
2. Use Markov inequality to get the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^ { +\infty}\mathbb P\left\{\left|\xi_n\right|\gt\epsilon \right\}$ and use the Borel-Cantelli lemma.